# How can I find a <li> elements in a page using Protractor?

Tags: protractor

The Protractor documentation page gives the following example:

Finding Sub-Elements example

```
element(by.css('some-css')).all(by.tag('tag-within-css'));
```

It does not appear to be syntactically correct and gives an error with Typescript using the latest definitions. Can someone help explain how this should be done and point out the error? Is this a definiton error or an error with the documentation.

Comment: i think it is by.tagName() what error text is shown? the documentation isn't as fast developed as protractor itself, so maybe just a missing or wrong documentation snippet. example: element(by.css('some-css')).all(by.tagName('li'));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a plain css selector.

```
$$('.some-css li')
element.all('.some-css li')
```

Or:

```
$('.some-css').$$('li')
```